Install GCC and G++ on Windows in a GitHub Actions CI/CD Workflow
I'm setting up a GitHub Actions CI/CD workflow and need to install gcc and g++ on a Windows runner to compile C/C++ code. I want the installation to be fully automated, as part of the CI/CD pipeline, without any manual intervention.
I've tried a few approaches:

Using Chocolatey: It seems like a good option since Chocolatey can manage packages in Windows. I tried adding a command to install mingw, which includes gcc and g++, but I'm not sure about the best practices for adding MinGW to the PATH in GitHub Actions. (but doesn't work...)

Using MSYS2: Another option could be installing MSYS2 and using pacman to get gcc and g++, but it feels a bit more complex and might slow down the CI/CD pipeline due to the setup steps. (But doesn't work too...)


My goal is to have a straightforward solution that installs gcc and g++ on the Windows runner in GitHub Actions, so I can compile C/C++ files as part of my CI pipeline. Here’s what I have so far in my YAML file, using Chocolatey, but I’m not entirely sure if it’s optimal:
Here my runner,
name: Build Binary Windows

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main 
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [windows-latest]
        python-version: [3.8, 3.9, 3.10.x, 3.11, 3.12]
      fail-fast: false

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}

      - name: Install dependencies & Build binary
        working-directory: ./tool
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
          .\setup.bat
          python -m PyInstaller `
            --collect-all z3        `
            --collect-all pyvex     `
            --collect-all angr      `
            --collect-all unicorn   `
            --collect-all cle       `
            --onefile --name capierre_binary src/__main__.py

      - name: Tests Fonctionnels
        working-directory: ./tool
        run: |
          ./launch_tests.bat "fonctionnel"

My setup.bat is like this:
@echo off

where choco >nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
    echo Installation de Chocolatey...
    powershell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; Invoke-Expression ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"
)

choco install mingw -y

setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin"

gcc --version

Is this the best approach, or is there a more efficient way to set up GCC and G++ for a GitHub Actions workflow on Windows ? Would MSYS2 offer better compatibility or speed? Any advice or improvements would be appreciated. Thanks you !

I use it in my yml file:
- name: Setup C/C++ Compiler
  id: setup-compiler
  uses: rlalik/setup-cpp-compiler@master
  with:
    compiler: gcc-latest

- name: Verify GCC Installation
  run: |
    gcc --version
    g++ --version

From this github: https://github.com/rlalik/setup-cpp-compiler
